# Django Rest Framework - Create method on ViewSet and Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I am creating my own authentication. Should override de create method on the serializer or on the viewset? What is the diference between them. I was following this tutorial and I don't know why the guy overloaded

https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am creating my own authentication. Should override de create method on the serializer or on the viewset?

There's no relation between authentication and overriding create method.

> What is the diference between them.

The serializer is responsible to deserialize the data which is done in its `create` / `update` methods.
The view is the glue between the pagination, throttling, serializer, parsers/renderers and so on. The view connects all those components. Its `create` method will deal with the specific steps for object creation:

- create the serializer
- ensure the incoming data are valid
- call the serializer's `save` - which will later call the serializer's `create`
- return the created instance or the errors.